# float:right behaves differently in chrome and safari when using internal style sheet instead of inline style

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm working through an example on making configurable drop-downs, from [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#).  It's still a work in progress, but I was trying to keep things clean, and move my inline style declarations to an internal style sheet in the head of the html file.

[Here's a fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/3xbcF/).

What's weird is line 9 of the html, shown here as the second span line:

```html
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#" class="uiwidgetcontent uiborderall" style="width: 200px;">
        <span>Please select the country</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" style="float:right;"></span>
    </a></dt>
```

This works fine, as I would expect, across all browsers.  But in the styling in the header, I put the same thing, in the `span:last-child` line.  (I left the whole style section for context):

```css
    .uiborderall {
        border-radius: 18px;
    }
    .uiwidgetcontent {
        background-color: #abc;
    }
    .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    .dropdown dd { position: relative; }
    .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { text-decoration: none; outline: none; display: inline-block;}
    .dropdown dt a:hover, .dropdown dt a:focus { color: #5d4617; border: 1px solid #5d4617;}
    .dropdown dt a {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #d4ca9a;}
    .dropdown dt a span:first-child {cursor: pointer; padding: 5px; display: inline-block; }
    .dropdown dt a span:last-child {cursor: pointer; float: right; margin-right: 10px; }
    .dropdown dd ul { display:none; left:0px;  position:absolute; top:1px; width:auto; min-width:170px; list-style:none; }
    .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
    .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
    .dropdown dd ul li a:hover {}
```

I should be able to delete the inline style from the `<span>` element, and it should fall back to the internal style sheet.  In Firefox and IE, this works fine.  However, in Chrome and Safari, when I do this, the `float: right` from the internal style sheet seems to be ignored.  For what it's worth, in chrome at least, `float:right` is still set on the appropriate span.  The renderer just seemingly ignores it.

Is there a way for me to use the `float:right` in a style sheet on the big 4 browsers, or must I put it inline in the element?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible to post a link to a functional example so we can tinker with it?

Comment: Try adding `!important` in your stylesheet - perhaps it's being overridden by other styles. Inline styles have a higher weight than those in a stylesheet.

Comment: @showdev - See my OP, under "Here's a fiddle for it".  http://jsfiddle.net/3xbcF/

Comment: @MarkParnell It was worth a shot, but adding !important into the fiddle and then removing the inline style gave me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need to place your `float` elements before the content you wish it to float around?

I reversed your `:first-child` and `:last-child` css styles, reversed the order of your spans, and removed the inline style and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/3xbcF/1/

```
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown"> <dt><a href="#" class="uiwidgetcontent uiborderall" style="width: 200px;">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
        <span>Please select the country</span>
    </a></dt>
```

css:

```
.dropdown dt a span:last-child {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown dt a span:first-child {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks great.  I'm still getting used to CSS layouts, and I'm sure there's a general rule I can get from this.  Is it "always put elements you want to float ahead of the inline ones"?  And do you know why it worked in IE and FireFox?  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the rule.  The fact that it worked in IE/FF and  Chrome (if you used inline style) is probably due to the browsers trying to help you out when you break the rule.